# ! Package pdftex.def Error: File `./filename-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found

Tags: image, latex, pdflatex

when i try to compile this

```
\documentclass{jprr}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[outdir=./]{epstopdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{/home/name/taiwan.eps}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I am getting this error all the time

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `./taiwan-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...
```

I am using Textworks, pdfLaTeX.

Please help.

Comment: Try compiling with the `--shell-escape` option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On ubuntu, installing the texlive-font-utils package solved the issue for me.

```
sudo apt install texlive-font-utils
```

I noticed the "repstopdf: not found system returned with code 32512" error before the "converted-to.pdf' not found" error. I tried to run "repstopdf" and the shell gave me the solution:

```
$ repstopdf

Command 'repstopdf' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install texlive-font-utils
```